# what is the Capped collection limit via programing

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, spring-data

I try to create/Modify capped collection via java/Spring data programing , I am using BasicDBObject and my Map will set in that dbObject , While i try to run the program , Small int value working fine but If i go with 2 GB of  int value then error  coming like as int values too long

I tried different datatype (BigInt,long,String .. etc ) its giving error , The program only expecting int value not other datatype .

```
Map<String, Object> commandArguments = new BasicDBObject();
commandArguments.put(CONVERT_TO_CAPPED,COLLECTION_NAME);
commandArguments.put(SIZE, 2147483648);
BasicDBObject command = new BasicDBObject(commandArguments);
Document commandResult = database.runCommand(command);}
```

Comment: The highest possible value for an integer in Java is 2147483647 so the value you're passing - 2147483648 - is simply too large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed

```
commandArguments.put(SIZE, 2147483648);
```

to

```
commandArguments.put(SIZE, 2147483648l);
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30477585)

Comment: @Vusal looks like an answer to me. Maybe not a *good* one, but still an answer. Maybe it ahould be downvoted, but not deleted

Comment: its solve my problem , because Mongo DB datatype is bigInt64